# Failed to build APK for flutter app and show me this error

Tags: flutter, dart, apk

I am trying to build a release APK for flutter app for existing app ,when I run `flutter build apk --release`, I got this error

**I built the app before upgrading Flutter to Channel beta (now I am using flutter to develop a website**

Can anyone help me please?

```
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration 
 ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath'.

 > Could not download mockito-core.jar (org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19)

   > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/mockito- 
 core-1.10.19.jar'.

     > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/e8546f5bef4e061d8dd73895b4e8f40e3fe6effe? 
        response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22mockito-core-1.10.19.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvZTg1NDZmNWJlZjRlMDYxZDhkZDczODk1YjRlOGY0MGUzZmU2ZWZmZT9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMm1vY2tpdG8tY29yZS0xLjEwLjE5LmphciUyMiIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTYwMzY1NDc2MX0sIklwQWRkcmVzcyI6eyJBV1M6U291cmNlSXAiOiIwLjAuMC4wLzAifX19XX0_&Signature=lu5rAbocUI2DuLDQ79CKz2UnjGl1smkhuOD3cR~iEunjBAfYD6VYxTLZD5vuiHnmr7avMhSI96FKGjaXzKSolqEGPSieDVuXqSMaJ7HryIRL693ykuFQi-RpTgk9k6PNJLPkcWjhrlsmJzNejwr0PwXtsJytAEUhsLhIR4MPey04ryOGTn~tFLMuOzCR46bYW0Bd8yyFA~cygPipbqRHc8M-Yj2Fjp-FfAUouQTIrEEdDmh2QgtiKpyBRSSmKbUvFf9gQ5GJa13P30mjyFHuHpK8J5hexyatUSOmDFbFYta2vQR7h-dpBTlZFkh901DHQq2xVhoj-xsZI-L0HxzzA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.

        > d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net



 * Try:

  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more 
  log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.



  * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


   BUILD FAILED in 24s
    Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           26.7s
    Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Try switching back to `stable` and then build  the APK

Comment: @Hamza I switched to stable, but another problem occurred, so I deleted the flutter sdk and download it again, now it is working fine.. Thanks for the help

Comment: Quick tip, in case you need to work with `stable`, `beta`, `master` channel a lot? Download all of them, and the next you need to work, you can simple change the path to flutter SDK and enable whatever you want to work with, like web, app or desktop :)

Comment: How can I do this ? Because I need to wok with more then one channel , I am developing  app and web using flutter. If you can help me with that

Comment: I think the conversation might be lengthy, can you catch me on linkedin? Here's the link: https://www.linkedin.com/in/m-hamzashakeel

Comment: I sent you an invitation for connecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to switch to **stable**, but another problem occurred, so I deleted the flutter SDK and download it again, now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add checkReleaseBuilds property under lintOptions into your build.gradle file under the android/app folder. Like this:

```
 android {

     // Something else about compileSdkVersion, etc.

     lintOptions {
         disable 'InvalidPackage'
         checkReleaseBuilds false
     }
 }
```

Comment: I tried to switch to stable, but another problem occurred, so I deleted the flutter SDK and download it again, now it is working fine.. Thanks for the help @Akif